# PostgreSQL slow JOIN with CASE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, case, postgresql-performance

In my database I have a table that contains ~3500 records and as a part of more complicated query I've tried to perform inner join on itself using "CASE" condition just as you can see below.

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table AS t1
JOIN some_table AS t2 ON t1.type = t2.type
    AND CASE
       WHEN t1.type = 'ab' THEN t1.first = t2.first
       WHEN t1.type = 'cd' THEN t1.second = t2.second
       -- Column type contains only one of 2 possible varchar values
    END;
```

The problem is this query is performed for 3.2 - 4.5 seconds while next request is performed in 40 - 50 milliseconds.

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table AS t1
JOIN some_table AS t2 ON t1.type = t2.type
    AND (t1.first = t2.first OR t1.second = t2.second)
```

Also according to the execution plan in first case database processes ~5.8 millions of records while table contains only ~3500. There are next indexes on this table: (id), (type), (type, first), (type, second).

We are using next version:
PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120
313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16), 64-bit

Any ideas why PostgreSQL works so weird in this case?

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement. (As a general advice, in the where clause use AND/OR instead of case expressions.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Test this one:

```
select *
from
    some_table as t1
    join
    some_table as t2 on
        t1.type = t2.type
        and
        (
            t1.type = 'ab' and t1.first = t2.first
            or
            t1.type = 'cd' and t1.second = t2.second
        )
```

For a better performance create an index based on a function:

```
create or replace function f (_type text, _first int, _second int)
returns integer as $$
    select case _type when 'ab' then _first else _second end;
$$ language sql immutable;

create index i on some_table(f(type, first, second));
```

Use that index on the query:

```
select *
from
    some_table as t1
    join
    some_table as t2 on
        t1.type = t2.type
        and
        f(t1.type, t1.first, t1.second) = f(t1.type, t2.first, t2.second)
```

Comment: It works just fine, thanks a lot. No ideas why query with CASE performs so slowly?

Comment: @legacy - the CASE in JOIN condition is pretty big trap for optimizer - probably Postgres's planner selected nested loop based plan - and your example is Cartesian product 3500*3500 rows, and you have to evaluate CASE expression for every combination - so 5sec is pretty fine time for pretty unhappy query.

Comment: Thanks for this example. That helped me very much to correct my own errors in my LEFT JOIN - CASE WHEN SQL query